# Re: How to detect and end game when a pygame sprite runs into its tail (using screen.get_at)?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I created a snake-like game in which the user moves the sprite, and the sprite leaves a trail. If the user runs into the trail he's created, I'd like the game to end, and the player to lose.

As the sprite moves, it makes a white trail on a black background. If I can detect that the user-controlled sprite will hit one of the white areas (its 'tail'), I can create an `if` statement that leads to a game loss.

I use the [Surface.get_at()][1] function to grab the color of the space the sprite will move into, and checking if this color is black or white. If it's white, that means it's the sprite's tail, and the game ends in a loss.

Here's the code:

In the `player.update()`:

```
if (screen.get_at((player_next_x, player_next_y)) != BACKGROUND_COLOUR):
    # player hit tail
```

However, this isn't working, and I know why:

1) I don't know how to define `(player_next_x)` or `(player_next_y)` while taking into account the user's input on the direction keys.

2) I tried this just using `(player.rect.x)` and `(player.rect.y)`, which I had already defined, and of course the system closed immediately because it detected a "collision" with its current position (which is white).

Here is the full code, if it helps:

```
import pygame
import os
import time

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    # -- Methods
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([15, 15])
        self.image.fill(WHITE)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0


    def changespeed(self, x, y):
        self.change_x += x
        self.change_y += y


    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
        self.rect.y += self.change_y

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([800, 600])

pygame.display.set_caption('The Etch-a-Sketch Game')

myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Times', 20)
textsurface = myfont.render('This is the Etch-a-Sketch Game', False, (255, 255, 255))
screen.blit(textsurface,(0,0))

myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Times', 15)
textsurface = myfont.render('Feel free to draw, but if you cross your own path, you will die.', False, (255, 255, 255))
screen.blit(textsurface,(0,20))


player = Player(400, 300)
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites_list.add(player)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False

while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.changespeed(-3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.changespeed(3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.changespeed(0, -3)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.changespeed(0, 3)

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.changespeed(3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.changespeed(-3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.changespeed(0, 3)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.changespeed(0, -3)

    player.update()

    if (screen.get_at((player.rect.x, player.rect.y)) != WHITE):
        myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Times', 20)
        textsurface = myfont.render('You have lost the Etch-a-Sketch Game.', False, (255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(textsurface,(0,0))

    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(250)

pygame.quit ()
```

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward way is to compute the step and check whether you just stomped on a white space.  If this doesn't fit with the design of your timing engine, then peek at the next location, just as you would take the step:

```
def peek_next(self):
    return (self.rect.x + self.change_x,
            self.rect.y + self.change_y)

...
player_next_x, player_next_y = player.peek_next()
if (screen.get_at((player_next_x, player_next_y)) != BACKGROUND_COLOUR):
# player hit tail
```

Or feed the new position directly to `get_at`:

```
if screen.get_at(player.peek_next()) != BACKGROUND_COLOUR:
# player bit own tail; dies of poisoning
```